# Windows XP User Permissions - local machine

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, user-management, users

I want to have 2 types of accounts on my machine: admin (easy) and a user account.

What permissions should the user account have and how should I set them?

Permissions should include everything except install and uninstall of programs, deletetion of Program Files and Windows folders or files in them.

I set the account to Limited from control panel and it seems to stop people from moving icons to quick launch as well, which is just stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is too broad; what do you *want* normal users to be able to do, and/or what do you want to *prevent* them from doing?

Comment: As Cocowalla said, this is difficult to answer without knowing exactly how you want the limited user accounts to behave.

Comment: I briefly described what I want to allow them to do.
It would help if you could indicate how to do this, especially if there would be options to check regarding permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for just the standard 'Users' group permissions. If you add a user only to the 'Users' group, it can run most programs and can add, delete, or change items under its own 'Documents and Settings' subfolder (including the quicklaunch bar).  Beyond that, it can only modify files and folders if explicitly granted access to them.  'Users' also have only very restricted access to things in the 'Windows' folder.  This is the most prudent acces to give regular users, and we add our standard 'domain user' accounts only to this folder on local workstations.

Comment: Thank you, Nedm.

Where can I change a user account to that please? From Control Panel I only have 2 options: Administrator and Limited User.

Comment: Sure, from the control panel open 'Administrative Tools' > 'Computer Management' and select 'Local Users and Groups' in the left-hand pane. From there you can select a user and verify that they're only in the groups you want under the 'member of' tab.  You can also browse the groups to seewho the members are.  Make sure the users you want to have this access are only in the 'Users' group and not in the 'Administrators' or 'Power Users' groups.